# Convert function iterative to recursive

Tags: c

How I can pass this function of iterative to recursive

```
void triangulo(int max)
    {
        int i, j;
        for(i = 1; i <= max; i++)
        {
            for(j = 0; j < i; j++)
                printf("%d", j + 1);
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
```

Anyone has any idea? or it is impossible to do this?

**update**

```
void triangulo(int n, int i, int j)
{
    if(i <= n)
    {
        if(j < i)
        {
            printf("%d", j + 1);
            triangulo(n, i, j + 1);
        }
        if (j == i)
        {
            printf("\n");
            triangulo(n, i + 1, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: change the `for` to an `if` whose branches are the last case and a function call

Comment: please you can do it in pseudocode

Answer (score 1):

Try this : Here I make `i` and `j` as arguments because in each recursion they have different values.

```
void triangulo(int max,int i,int j) //make i and j as arguments
{
    if(i<max)
    {
        if(j<max)
        {
            printf("%d",j);
            triangulo(max, i, ++j);//dont use post increment operation
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\n");
            triangulo(max , ++i, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Generally,

- use `if` and `else` for condition and
- send arguments at the end of it as what may happen in iterative method.

Comment: I want to do fully recursive

Comment: Can you be more precise... I'm not able to understand @cheroky

Comment: without using any loop

Comment: @cherokt updated... I hope this helps :).

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: Your function has too many problems. It's got syntax errors, it's got logic errors, and it doesn't work. Test it, please.

Comment: @RSahu thanks for the mention...

Comment: @cheroky I've updated...

Comment: Your program does not work

Comment: @cheroky .... Ya found out the culprit. It was the post increment operator... Generally post increment operator increments after the operation has been performed... So it doesn't increment before every function call and this gave rise to infinite loop... To fix it use the pre-increment loop as I've mentioned above :)

Answer (score 0):

I hope that links below may help:

http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/replaceIterationWithRecursion.html

http://webrewrite.com/iteration-versus-recursion-which-one-you-choose/

[What is the difference between iteration and recursion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19794739/what-is-the-difference-between-iteration-and-recursion)

[Converting an iterative function to recursive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7939493/converting-an-iterative-function-to-recursive?rq=1)